# For loop in OpenCl kernel rolling through global memory float array

Tags: opencl

I feel I don't understand a basic parallel programming concept. The kernel below is a simple/contrived example that reproduces the problem I'm having. It attempts to use all the values in "points" to calculate a value and assign it to all of the items in "blocks." I want to push the limits for the size of these arrays. While I can make the "blocks" array quit large (>100 million floats), I get an "invalid command queue" error when "points" is filled with more than ~100 thousand floats (after calling clFinish immediately after clEnqueueNDRangeKernel). Could any of you help me understand why?

```
__kernel void openClTesting (__global float *blocks, __global float *points, int pointsCount)
    {
        int globalId = get_global_id(0);
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < pointsCount; i++)
        {
            count++;
        }
        blocks[globalId] = count;
    };
```

Some Device Info:

```
CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE = 49,152  
CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE = 2,147,483,648  
CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE = 536,870,912
```

Host Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CL\opencl.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_POINTS 100000
#define NUM_BLOCKS 100000000

struct openClData
{
cl_device_id deviceId = NULL;
cl_uint numDevices;
cl_uint numPlatforms;
cl_int ret;
cl_platform_id *platforms = NULL;
cl_context context;
cl_command_queue commandQueue;
cl_program program;
cl_kernel kernel;
char* kernelCode;
cl_uint kernelCodeSize;
size_t globalItemSize;
size_t localItemSize = 1;
};


char* getKernelCode();
void printErrorLog(openClData oclData);
void printRet(openClData oclData, int line);
int countFileChars(const char *fileName);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
openClData oclData;
oclData.globalItemSize = NUM_POINTS;
oclData.kernelCode = getKernelCode();
std::cout << oclData.kernelCode << std::endl;
oclData.kernelCodeSize = strlen(oclData.kernelCode);

int numPoints = NUM_POINTS;
int numBlocks = NUM_BLOCKS;
cl_long localMemSize = 0, globalMemSize = 0, maxAllocMemSize = 0;
float *blocks = new float[numBlocks]{0};
float *points = new float[numPoints]{0};

//prepare platform, device, context and command queue
oclData.ret = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &oclData.numPlatforms);
printRet(oclData, __LINE__);
oclData.platforms = (cl_platform_id *)malloc(oclData.numPlatforms * sizeof(cl_platform_id));
oclData.ret = clGetPlatformIDs(oclData.numPlatforms, oclData.platforms, NULL);
printRet(oclData, __LINE__);
oclData.ret = clGetDeviceIDs(oclData.platforms[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &oclData.deviceId, &oclData.numDevices);
printRet(oclData, __LINE__);
oclData.context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &oclData.deviceId, NULL, NULL, &oclData.ret);
printRet(oclData, __LINE__);
oclData.commandQueue = clCreateCommandQueue(oclData.context, oclData.deviceId, 0, &oclData.ret);
printRet(oclData, __LINE__);
//prepare cl_mem objects
cl_mem memObjBlocks = clCreateBuffer(oclData.context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(float) * numBlocks, NULL, &oclData.ret);
printRet(oclData, __LINE__);
cl_mem memObjPoints = clCreateBuffer(oclData.context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(float) * numPoints, NULL, &oclData.ret);
printRet(oclData, __LINE__);
oclData.ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(oclData.commandQueue, memObjBlocks, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float) * numBlocks, blocks, 0, NULL, NULL);
printRet(oclData, __LINE__);
oclData.ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(oclData.commandQueue, memObjPoints, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float) * numPoints, points, 0, NULL, NULL);
printRet(oclData, __LINE__);
//prepare program
oclData.program = clCreateProgramWithSource(oclData.context, 1, (const char**)&oclData.kernelCode, (const size_t *)&oclData.kernelCodeSize, &oclData.ret);
printRet(oclData, __LINE__);
oclData.ret = clBuildProgram(oclData.program, 1, &oclData.deviceId, NULL, NULL, NULL);
printRet(oclData, __LINE__);
if (oclData.ret == CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE) printErrorLog(oclData);
oclData.kernel = clCreateKernel(oclData.program, "openClTesting", &oclData.ret);
printRet(oclData, __LINE__);
//set arguments
oclData.ret = clSetKernelArg(oclData.kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &memObjBlocks);
printRet(oclData, __LINE__);
oclData.ret = clSetKernelArg(oclData.kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &memObjPoints);
printRet(oclData, __LINE__);
oclData.ret = clSetKernelArg(oclData.kernel, 2, sizeof(int), &numPoints);
printRet(oclData, __LINE__);
//run
oclData.ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(oclData.commandQueue, oclData.kernel, 1, NULL, &oclData.globalItemSize, &oclData.localItemSize, 0, NULL, NULL);
printRet(oclData, __LINE__);
oclData.ret = clFinish(oclData.commandQueue);
printRet(oclData, __LINE__);
oclData.ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(oclData.commandQueue, memObjBlocks, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float) * numBlocks, blocks, 0, NULL, NULL);
printRet(oclData, __LINE__);
oclData.ret = clFinish(oclData.commandQueue);
printRet(oclData, __LINE__);
//print some device info
oclData.ret = clGetDeviceInfo(oclData.deviceId, CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE, sizeof(cl_ulong), &localMemSize, 0);
std::cout << "CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE = " << localMemSize << '\n';
oclData.ret = clGetDeviceInfo(oclData.deviceId, CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE, sizeof(cl_long), &globalMemSize, 0);
std::cout << "CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE = " << globalMemSize << '\n';
oclData.ret = clGetDeviceInfo(oclData.deviceId, CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE, sizeof(cl_long), &maxAllocMemSize, 0);
std::cout << "CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE = " << maxAllocMemSize << '\n';

//clean up
oclData.ret = clFlush(oclData.commandQueue);
printRet(oclData, __LINE__);
oclData.ret = clFinish(oclData.commandQueue);
printRet(oclData, __LINE__);
oclData.ret = clReleaseKernel(oclData.kernel);
printRet(oclData, __LINE__);
oclData.ret = clReleaseProgram(oclData.program);
printRet(oclData, __LINE__);
oclData.ret = clReleaseMemObject(memObjBlocks);
printRet(oclData, __LINE__);
oclData.ret = clReleaseMemObject(memObjPoints);
printRet(oclData, __LINE__);
oclData.ret = clReleaseCommandQueue(oclData.commandQueue);
printRet(oclData, __LINE__);
oclData.ret = clReleaseContext(oclData.context);
printRet(oclData, __LINE__);
for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    std::cout << blocks[i] << std::endl;
}
delete blocks;
delete points;
return 0;
}

char* getKernelCode()
{
char* kernelCode =
    "__kernel void openClTesting (__global float *blocks, __global float *points, int pointsCount)"
    "{"
    "   int globalId = get_global_id(0);"
    "   int count = 0;"
    "   for (int i = 0; i < pointsCount; i++)"
    "   {"
    "       count++;"
    "   }"
    "blocks[globalId] = count;"
    "}";
return kernelCode;
}

void printErrorLog(openClData oclData)
{
size_t log_size;
clGetProgramBuildInfo(oclData.program, oclData.deviceId, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, 0, NULL, &log_size);
char *log = (char *)malloc(log_size);
clGetProgramBuildInfo(oclData.program, oclData.deviceId, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, log_size, log, NULL);
std::cout << log;
free(log);
}

void printRet(openClData oclData, int line)
{
std::cout << line << ", " << oclData.ret << std::endl;
}

int countFileChars(const char *fileName)
{
std::ifstream ifs(fileName);
ifs.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
size_t count = ifs.tellg();
ifs.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);
return count;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into what your OpenCL implementation returns for [`CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE` and `CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE `](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html) for example, and how those values relate to the apparent limits you're running into? Regarding the "invalid command queue" error, can you please post your host code? (Buffer allocations, enqueueing, etc.) Without this info I doubt you'll get much help.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time.  I've updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

A few things I notice:

- You're launching `NUM_POINTS` work-items, but write the result of each to `blocks[globalId]` - which has `NUM_BLOCKS` items. So that's undefined behaviour when NUM_POINTS is greater than NUM_BLOCKS. It also explains why varying NUM_BLOCKS does nothing (outside of the above restriction): aside from the memory allocation, the value of NUM_BLOCKS has no effect. (And the memory allocation limit you found roughly matches the CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE value for your implementation.)
- You might be running into a kernel timeout condition here. 100000 loop iterations in a single work-item is quite a lot. Depending on the OpenCL implementation, kernels can be killed off if they take too long to run. Consider making better use of the thread-parallelism available, and split the work more horizontally across work-items, rather than looping. Many, shortish-running work-items are typically better than few long-running ones.

Answer (score 0):

On a general note, `localItemSize = 1;` should be avoided, because it forces every OpenCL work group to consist of a single work item which will reduce you parallelism to the number of work groups that your compute device can run in parallel, which will be much less than the number of work items it can run. You can simply pass `NULL` for the local item size instead to have the OpenCL implementation figure out a reasonable value in its own:

```
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &globalSize, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

This may also be the source of your error because you are creating `NUM_POINTS` work groups but the size of the queue on the device is memory limited (`CL_DEVICE_QUEUE_ON_DEVICE_MAX_SIZE`).